# How do I search through a list of dictionaries in python when I want to find multiple dictionaries which have multipe same values for multiple keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

For example, I have a list of dictionaries like this one:

```
[{'name':'Mike', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Steve', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Sally', 'hobby':'chess', 'job':'teacher'} ]
```

and I want to search for all dictionaries which have same values for keys `'hobby'` and `'job'`. For example  `'hobby':'skiing'`, `'job':'doctor'`. The output should be:

```
[{'name':'Mike', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Steve', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}]
```

My code looks something like this:

```
name=raw_input('Name: ') 
hobby=raw_input('Hobby: ') 
job= raw_input('Job: ') 
def first_searsh(input, key): 
    out = [] 
    for item in list: 
        if item[key] == input: 
            out.append(item) 
return out
```

and I have written separate functions for all keys like this one:

```
def name_search(): 
    if name != "": 
        out_1 = first_search(name, 'name') 
    else: 
        pass 
return out_1
```

My real dictionaries have 10 keys and I don't know how to connect those separate search functions so that the output only displays dictionaries that have all same values, not all dictionaries that have any of the values entered

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: You should include your code to your question as your attempts...not in comments

Comment: we aren't allowed to use SQL for this project. the records are stored in txt file and I decided to convert them to dictionaries because I thought it would be easier to work with a list of dictionaries instead of strings. the file in my example would consist of multiple lines which look like this: name|hobby|job

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [{'name':'Mike', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Steve', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Sally', 'hobby':'chess', 'job':'teacher'} ]  
hobby = 'skiing'
job = 'doctor'

result = [i for i in x if i['hobby'] == hobby and i['job'] == job]

print(result)
```

prints:

```
[{'hobby': 'skiing', 'job': 'doctor', 'name': 'Mike'},
 {'hobby': 'skiing', 'job': 'doctor', 'name': 'Steve'}]
```

or, a more generic solution:

```
def search_for(d, lst):
    return [i for i in lst if all(i[target_key] == target_value for target_key, target_value in d.items())]

dict_to_search_for = {
    'hobby':'skiing',
    'job':'doctor'
}

lst = [{'name':'Mike', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Steve', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Sally', 'hobby':'chess', 'job':'teacher'} ]

search_for(dict_to_search_for, lst)
```

- `dict_to_search_for` is a dictionary that holds the key-value combos  you are trying to match.
- `lst` is your list
- `search_for` takes as arguments the dictionary and the list.
- `[i for i in lst if all(i[target_key] == target_value for target_key, target_value in d.items())]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that collects every dictionary in your `lst` that matches [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) of your key-value combos.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't have time to try to incorporate it in my code now, but I think that the generic approach could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more Pythonic ways of doing this, but simply iterating through the list for matches to key:value pairs work, using 'and' to specify that both job and hobby conditions must be met.

If an item is a match, append it to a new list, and Bob's yer uncle.

```
lst = [{'name':'Mike', 'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Steve',     
'hobby':'skiing', 'job':'doctor'}, {'name':'Sally', 'hobby':'chess',   
'job':'teacher'} ]

lst2 = []
for item in lst:
    if item['hobby'] == 'skiing' and item['job'] == 'doctor':
       lst2.append(item)

print lst2
```

Comment: My real dictionaries contain 10 keys, and the user enters the values. The if would be too long if i used it that way.